# Multiple Tuple to Two-Pair Tuple in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples

What is the nicest way of splitting this:

```
tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
```

into this:

```
tuples = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```

Assuming that the input always has an even number of values.

Comment: You may not want to a variable named tuple as it overwrites the builtin function tuple().

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`zip()` is your friend:

```
t = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
zip(t[::2], t[1::2])
```

Comment: +1 because it's pretty and I didn't know about the [::] syntax

Comment: doesn't works for tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i') # note the last 'i', that makes the tuples odd-length

Comment: @dfa: what do you mean it doesn't work? is it specified how new list should be formed in case of odd-length input?

Comment: ops, I've just read: "Assuming that the input always has an even number of values."

Comment: @dfa: well if the input is has an odd number of elements, what should happen to the left over element? Should it be a one element tuple or should it be (x, None)? You have to massage you input according to the expected output.

Answer (score 15):

```
[(tuple[a], tuple[a+1]) for a in range(0,len(tuple),2)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Or, using `itertools` (see the [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) for `grouper`):

```
from itertools import izip
def group2(iterable):
   args = [iter(iterable)] * 2
   return izip(*args)

tuples = [ab for ab in group2(tuple)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I present this code based on [Peter Hoffmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756580/117870) as a response to [dfa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756550/17899786#comment568676_756602).

It is guaranteed to work whether or not your tuple has an even number of elements.

```
[(tup[i], tup[i+1]) for i in range(0, (len(tup)/2)*2, 2)]
```

The `(len(tup)/2)*2` range parameter calculates the highest even number less or equal to the length of the tuple so it is guaranteed to work whether or not the tuple has an even number of elements.

The result of the method is going to be a list. This can be converted to tuples using the `tuple()` function.

**Sample:**

```
def inPairs(tup):
    return [(tup[i], tup[i+1]) for i in range(0, (len(tup)/2)*2, 2)]

# odd number of elements
print("Odd Set")
odd = range(5)
print(odd)
po = inPairs(odd)
print(po)

# even number of elements
print("Even Set")
even = range(4)
print(even)
pe = inPairs(even)
print(pe)
```

Output

```
Odd Set
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
Even Set
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a general recipe for any-size chunk, if it might not always be 2:

```
def chunk(seq, n):
    return [seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]

chunks= chunk(tuples, 2)
```

Or, if you enjoy iterators:

```
def iterchunk(iterable, n):
    it= iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk= []
        try:
            for i in range(n):
                chunk.append(it.next())
        except StopIteration:
            break
        finally:
            if len(chunk)!=0:
                yield tuple(chunk)
```

Comment: I think you meant range(0, len(seq), n), rather than range(0, len(seq))