# idiomatic way to take groups of n items from a list in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

Given a list

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Is there any idiomatic (Pythonic) way to iterate over it as though it were

```
B = [(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6)]
```

other than indexing? That feels like a holdover from C:

```
for a1,a2 in [ (A[i], A[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(A), 2) ]:
```

I can't help but feel there should be some clever hack using itertools or slicing or something.

(Of course, two at a time is just an example; I'd like a solution that works for any n.)

Edit: related [Iterate over a string 2 (or n) characters at a time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162592/iterate-over-a-string-2-or-n-characters-at-a-time-in-python) but even the cleanest solution (accepted, using zip) doesn't generalize well to higher n without a list comprehension and *-notation.

Comment: I think your C holdover doesn't look that bad, but I'd write `A[i:i+1]` instead of `A[i], A[i+1]`. Easier to extend to arbitrary `n`.

Comment: Duplicate: What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335392/iteration-over-list-slices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760753/iterate-over-a-python-sequence-in-multiples-of-n

Comment: The [referenced accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162636/923794) actually has a clean, no-copy solution, and there is no need for a list comprehension or *-notation. In the end, you'll want to loop over the data somewhere, so any loop/comprehensions/generator does not come at an extra price. Encapsulate the referenced itertools.islice based solution into a function if you like it more compact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

i = grouper(3,range(100))
i.next()
(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This may not be subjectively idiomatic or avoid list comprehensions and * notation, but it is "pythonic" enough to be in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, I knew it existed somewhere. Thank you!