# list of elements

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate over a python sequence in multiples of n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760753/iterate-over-a-python-sequence-in-multiples-of-n)

How to list elements like: ['abcd', 'efghi'] ?

Using the next:

```
test = map(chr, range(97, 123))
for i in test:
if len(el) == 2:
    break
while len(i) != 4:
    i = i + i
el.append(i)
```

it shows: ['aaaa', 'bbbb']
and it's correct in this case

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Chomping up the alphabet in groups of four?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
>>> [''.join(test[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(test), 4)]
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'yz']
```