# pythonic way to explode a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I need to do the opposite of this

[Multiple Tuple to Two-Pair Tuple in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756550/multiple-tuple-to-two-pair-tuple-in-python)

Namely, I have a list of tuples

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

and need to produce this

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would personally do this

```
>>> tot = []
>>> for i in [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]:
...     tot.extend(list(i))
```

but I'd like to see something fancier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most efficient way to do it is this:

```
tuples = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
[item for t in tuples for item in t]
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here is [the comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/952993#952993) I did for various way to do it in a duplicate question.

I know someone is going to suggest this solution

```
sum(tuples, ())
```

But don't use it, it will create a new intermediate result list for each step! unless you don't care about performance and just want a compact solution.
For more details check [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/952952#952952)

In summary: sum is faster for small lists, but the performance degrades significantly with larger lists.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> tp = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> lst = list(itertools.chain(*tp))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Of course, if you don't need a list but an iterator, you can drop the `list()` conversion call.

Comment: you're showing how to chain three tuples, not a single list containing three tuples

Comment: Or: lst = list(chain.from_iterable(tp))

Comment: I already edited it, but it wasn't just three tuples but a "tuple of three tuples" - now changed to a list of tuples...

Comment: tuples of three tuples needs to have additional brackets when passed to function

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
reduce (lambda x,y: x+list(y), l, [])
```

Comment: If you go that way, `sum()` is simpler (but this approach creates a lot of intermediary lists).