# Logical task for Python programmers. Make tuple of lists from list

Tags: python, list

I need to make tuple of list with 2 items.

For example if I have list `range(10)`

I need to make tuple like this:

```
[(0,1),(2,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,9)]
```

How can I implement that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Tuple to Two-Pair Tuple in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756550/multiple-tuple-to-two-pair-tuple-in-python)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870652/pythonic-way-to-split-comma-separated-numbers-into-pairs/870677#870677

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the `itertools` docs:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    """
    >>> grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x')
    ["ABC", "DEF", "Gxx"]
    """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

This means that you can do:

```
[(el[0], el[1]) for el in grouper(2, range(10))]
```

Or more generally:

```
[(el[0], el[1]) for el in grouper(2, elements)]
```

Comment: I would write list(grouper(2, range(10)))

Answer (score 3):

Many different ways. Just to show off a few:

As list comprehension, where l is a sequence (i.e. integer indexes): `[(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(l),2)]`

As generator function, works for all iterables:

```
def some_meaningful_name(it):
    it = iter(it)
    while True:
        yield next(it), next(it)
```

Naive via list slicing (sucksy performance for larger lists) and copying, again using list comprehension: `[pair for pair in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])]`.

I like the second best, and it's propably the most pythonic and generic (and since it's a generator, it runs in constant space).

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done with [numpy](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy
elements = range(10)

elements = [tuple(e) for e in numpy.array(elements).reshape(-1,2).tolist()]
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```